# How to create a new array from an array using forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry for my poor English.

```
groups: [
 {
  id: 1,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "vegetable"},
   {name: "meat"}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "car"},
   {name: "train"}
  ]
 }
]
```

From the above array, I am trying to sort the names alphabetically by the associative array directly under groups.

```
let arr = [];
 groups.forEach(element => {
 arr = element.smallGroups.sort((a,b) => {
  let textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  let textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return (textA < textB) ? 1 : (textA > textB) ? -1 : 0;
 })
});
```

I was able to sort them alphabetically, but I cannot store all the arrays from forEach in an array called arr.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: `sort` is *inplace*, so `groups` will reflect the change after the loop is finished. No need to have `arr` at all. If you really want it in `arr`, then do `arr = groups` after the loop... but that looks like not very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`. I used destructuring to avoid modifications in the original array because `Array.prototype.sort` changes in place and modifies the input array.

```js
const groups = [
 {
  id: 1,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "vegetable"},
   {name: "meat"}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "car"},
   {name: "train"}
  ]
 }
]

let arr = groups.map(element => [...element.smallGroups].sort((a,b) => {
  let textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  let textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return (textA < textB) ? 1 : (textA > textB) ? -1 : 0;
}));
 
console.log(arr);
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `push()` to add new item in the array, though I think you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here:

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**Code Example:**

```js
let groups = [
 {
  id: 1,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "vegetable"},
   {name: "meat"}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  smallGroups: [
   {name: "car"},
   {name: "train"}
  ]
 }
];

let arr = groups.map(element => {
 return element.smallGroups.sort((a,b) => {
  let textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  let textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return (textA < textB) ? 1 : (textA > textB) ? -1 : 0;
 })
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used array [destructuring:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
let groups= [
  {
    id: 1,
    smallGroups: [{ name: "vegetable" }, { name: "meat" }],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    smallGroups: [{ name: "car" }, { name: "train" }],
  },
];


let arr = [];
// sort each and combine 
groups.forEach((element) => {
  let temp = element.smallGroups.sort((a, b) => {
    let textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    let textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
    return textA < textB ? 1 : textA > textB ? -1 : 0;
  });
  arr = [...arr, ...temp];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you need to create a copy `groups` array because you do not want to modify it and sort by alphabetical order the new array called `arr`.

```
let arr = [...groups];

arr.forEach((el) => {
    el.smallGroups.sort(function (a, b) {
        const first = a.name.toUpperCase();
        const second = b.name.toUpperCase();

        if (first > second) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (first < second) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    });
})
```